# Fill numbers in column between two numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, autofill

[image: Here's a link to the image]

So I'm trying to fill in the numbers between two cells in Google Sheets. I start with 270 and I need to get to 180 after several indefinite and varying empty cells in the column. I need the cells between them evenly filled. But how?

Comment: Okay I've added an image link. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to paste those values in the same column you need to do:

[image: 0]

then the formula will be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), )))+SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))-2)), 1, 0)*(A1-INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))))/(
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))-1))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

shorter:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(m, INDIRECT("A"&m)+
 SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&m-2)), 1, )*(A1-INDIRECT("A"&m))/(m-1))
 (MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))))
```

[image]